# Why am I getting errors when I define this C++ concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm following Josh Lospinoso's *C++ Crash Course* and I'm at a part where it's trying to show me an example of how to use concepts to constrain a method's parameters, and also wants me to use type_traits. However, I'm getting errors saying that it's argument list is missing and that it has an invalid combination of type specifiers. Here's the concept and the method:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept bool Averageable() {
    return std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && requires (T a, T b) {
        { a += b } -> T;
        { a / size_t{ 1 } } -> T;
    };
}

template <Averageable T>
T mean(const T* values, size_t length) {
    T result{};
    for (size_t i{}; i < length; i++) {
        result += values[i];
    }
    return result / length;
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into the question.

Comment: I notice the book was published in 2019. It's probably based on concepts as they were while they were still in the standardization process. There were several changes by C++20.

Comment: It is, thanks for pointing that out and sorry for not sharing the error output. I'll have to checkout the new stuff when I'm done with the book.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't edit answers into questions - it's quite confusing coming to a question and seeing the question code being the same as (modulo formatting) the answer code (and, more to the point, seeing a question about getting a concept error but having the concept declaration actually be completely correct).

Comment: Given that now you're getting "identifier '`concept`' is undefined" as your error, I suspect your compiler simply doesn't support concepts.

Comment: VS 2019's C++ compiler does supply concepts as of September 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have C++20 enabled in MVSC. Didn't think that had to be done but it did so everything is good now.

Comment: I think you should probably accept my answer below because it shows how to define concept in a right way.

Comment: My original answer does too, but for C++17.

Answer (score 4):

I think you defined your concept in a wrong way. This is how it should look like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Averageable =
    std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && requires (T a, T b) {
        { a += b          } -> std::same_as<T>;
        { a / size_t{ 1 } } -> std::same_as<T>;
    };
```

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:7,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:7,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Aconcept+Averageable+%3D%0A++++std::is_default_constructible%3CT%3E::value+%26%26+requires+(T+a,+T+b)+%7B%0A++++++++%7B+a+%2B%3D+b+%7D+-%3E+std::same_as%3CT%3E%3B%0A++++++++%7B+a+/+size_t%7B+1+%7D+%7D+-%3E+std::same_as%3CT%3E%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Atemplate+%3CAverageable+T%3E%0AT+mean(const+T*+values,+size_t+length)+%7B%0A++++T+result%7B%7D%3B%0A++++for+(size_t+i%7B%7D%3B+i+%3C+length%3B+i%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++++++result+%2B%3D+values%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+result+/+length%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:64.33578104138851,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1101,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-g+-Wall+-Werror+-fsanitize%3Dmemory+-fPIE++-fsanitize-memory-track-origins%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+11.0.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+11.0.1%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: I fixed up the concept definition but I'm still getting errors. I'm pretty sure I'm in C++20 so I don't know why it's not recognizing 'concept' as a keyword.

Comment: I added them to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @GrahamHornecker which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: I'm on 4.8.04084.

Comment: @GrahamHornecker this answer [works with MSVC too](https://godbolt.org/z/Ps9686TqG) **assuming that C++20 has been enabled**.

Comment: Wow I feel stupid, I assumed MSVC used the latest version of C++ always, but I have that set now. Thank you so much.